# grep filename and grep in the file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file in a directory that has the .txt ending, but before the name is always different point. I want in the file where changes the name "http". See,
so it does not work, unfortunately,

```
| Grep txt \\ |. Grep "http"
```

edit:
i have testet :

curl ftp://user:pw@ip:port/directory/ ls | grep ".txt" | xargs grep "http"

error : curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ls

curl ftp://user:pw@ip:port/directory/ printf "%s\n" *.txt | xargs grep "http"

error :

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: printf curl: (6) Could not resolve host: %s\n curl: (6) Could not resolve host: *.txt grep: invalid option -- '-' Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]... Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please show what the file contains, and your attempted code to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Your question is very unclear.  Unix is case-sensitive; write `grep` and not `Grep`.  Your command line syntax doesn't match what Bash allows.  The leading `|` is a syntax error (it needs to be preceded by a command).  The `|.` notation means the same as `| .` and that in turn tries to read a file `Grep` as if it was shell commands.  Not a good idea.

Comment: He may be using OS X, where I think the case doesn't matter.

Comment: `curl ftp://user:pw@ip:port/directory/ ls` are you trying to get a remote dir listing? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
ls | grep ".txt" | xargs grep "http"
```

Thanks to Jonathan's comment! it's better to do:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | xargs grep "http"
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler true and I remember reading somewhere that it's a better practice to do that instead of piping `ls` (but I have to admit that I don't remember the reason why).

Comment: Because it is hard to interpret the output of `ls` when the file names have spaces.  And that's using `ls` in either way.  The full set of contortions that are necessary don't bear thinking about.  `xargs` has to be fettled too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `find` and `grep`:

```
find /your/path -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep http "{}" \;
```

You can read that as "find in /your/path anything that is a file whose name ends in .txt and run grep http on it".

Comment: Use `+` in place of `\;` to get multiple files processed by a single `grep`.  You may have a correct interpretation of what's wanted; I don't understand the wording enough to know either way.